# Sonar 4.5.2 plugins and java 1.7

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

For Sonar 4.5.2, I have upgraded Sonar plugins to the versions compatible with 4.2.x http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix,
however after the upgrade:

1-  I could not find the widget “Most Violated Resources” to add into the dashboard, do you have the same issue ?

2-  Do you know which widget belongs to which plugin ?

3-  There are 2 plugins required Java 1.7: Findbugs and cpp . My projects failed with error message “The plugin is not supported with Java 1.6.0_85” because my projects use 1.6.0_85. Do you encounter this issue ? and what is the workaround, i.e. downgrade plugin version ? How do I know which plugin version that I should downgrade it to ?

Many thanks ahead,
/Ha

Comment: For my question 1: Missing widget “Most Violated Resources” is provided in Issues Density plugin, and has a new name “Most Violated Components”.

For my question 3: You can use java 1.6 to compile your code and use java 1.7 for Sonar analysis.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can find the Widget "Most Violated Resources" renamed as "Most Violated Components" in the Issues Density Plugin : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Density+Plugin
2. Same as 1.
3. With SonarQube 4.5.x you must use JRE/JDK 1.7u75+ but it doesn't mean you can't continue to compile your code with older version of JDK. See the Java Analyzer FAQ for the workaround : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ